# Display PHP array data into table cell with cell number

Tags: php, arrays, html-table

I have an array from database

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [cell] => 2
            [price] => 1543.65
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [cell] => 3
            [price] => 386.22
        )

)
```

and A table

```
<table>
    <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>12</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <?php
     print_r($sales);
     if(!empty($sales)) {
        foreach($sales as $sale) {

         if($sale->cell == 1) {echo "<td>".$sale->price."</td>";} else { echo "<td>0</td>"; }
         if($sale->cell == 2) {echo "<td>".$sale->price."</td>";} else { echo "<td>0</td>"; }
         ...
         if($sale->cell == 12) {echo "<td>".$sale->price."</td>";} else { echo "<td>0</td>"; }

        }

    } else {
    for($i=1; $i<=12; $i++) {
        echo "<td>0</td>";
    }
    }
    ?>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

I need to display price in same cell as it is in array. Now my problem is array size is not 12. Please help how can I display this on same cell as in `array['cell']`?

I want to display it as:

```
<tr>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>1543.65</td>
    <td>386.22</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
    </tr>
```

Your help and time is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand, completely, but this should do it:

```
echo '<tr>';
foreach($data as $value) {
    $array[$value->cell] = $value->price;
}
for($i = 0; $i <= 12; $i++) {
    echo '<td>';
    if(isset($array[$i])
        echo $array[$i];
    else echo '0';
    echo '</td>';
}
echo '</tr>';
```

where $data is the array you got from the database and $array is the same data but converted into an associative array.  This also assumes 12 columns, so it would be slightly more complex if the total number of columns needs to be flexible.

edit: actually, I just noticed that your array's index doesn't match the 'cell' value.  I fixed my code to reflect this, but if this is what your data looks like you should probably reevaluate your data structure.

Answer (score 0):

You can build your row like this:

```
echo "<tr>";
for ($i = 0; $i < 12; $i++){
    echo "<td>";
    if(isset($sale[$i]) && $sale[$i]->cell == $i) echo $sale[$i]->price;
    else echo 0;
    echo "</td>";
}
echo "</tr>";
```

Possible problem though, is if the items in the array are not in order. The best thing you can do is make sure they are.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
<table>
    <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>12</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <?php
    if(!empty($sales)) {
        //Create an array with 12 elements and initialize each with 0
        $salesArray = array_fill(1,12,0);

        foreach($sales as $sale) {
            //Override Cell Number Position in $salesArray so that if Cell number is present in $sales array, then it will have sale price, otherwise 0
            $salesArray[$sale->cell] = $sale->price;
        }

        //Sort it by key. Just in case 
        ksort($salesArray);

        foreach($salesArray as $salePrice)
        {
            echo "<td>".$salePrice."</td>";
        }
    } else {
    for($i=1; $i<=12; $i++) {
        echo "<td>0</td>";
    }
    }
    ?>
    </tr>
    </table>
```